# Wicket 1.5.RC3 Bug - "Header was already written"

Tags: maven, ireport

I was working on wicket 1.5.1. I tried to export file with iReport. 
Export is working but with this error :

> ERROR [org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper] Unexpected error
>   occurred java.lang.IllegalStateException: Header was already written
>   to response!

I guess this is a bug of maven 1.5-RC3 and was fixed 1.5.RC4. I have changed maven version to 1.5.RC4.2 .  But still i have same problem. 
do you have any idea?